# Hosting Asp .Net Core API on Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My API doesn't use any database or any authentication. API supports just basic functions.
Is there any way to host a .Net Core API on Android?

Comment: I am not sure you understand what you are asking... But in any case. You can turn your android phone to a web server with apache. Just google how. Here is a link as well https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-install-a-web-server-on-an-android-device/

Comment: @panoskarajohn I know there are HTTP server apps for android. What I am asking is self-hosting .Net Core API.

Comment: @emert117 Did you get any solution to host an API on android?

Comment: @sinsedrix take a look at https://www.hanselman.com/blog/exploring-a-minimal-web-api-with-aspnet-core-6

Comment: @emert117 nothing about hosting on android on this page